# How to open Foundation Reveal Modal with hash (#)

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, reveal.js

Can someone point me in a right direction if it is possible somehow.

I have an email I would like to send to users with a links to specific page. I have modals on that page and I would like to have page to be open with specific modal depending on url. 
Example:

```
domain.com/story/#story1
```

opens page with OPEN reveal modal with id `#story1`

I would really appreciate if someone could help.

I managed to have modal window open while navigating to the page via

```
("#Modal8").foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

Someone suggested that I use

```
<script>
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash === "#story8") {
        $('#Modal8').reveal({ 
            animation: 'fadeAndPop',                 //fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 300,                    //how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,           //if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //element that will close an open modal
        }); //You can use same modal or different modal to show success message
    } 
</script>
```

I have tried without success.

Comment: What is `ef('#Modal8')`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Expressionengine for my project, so I came up with a simple solution. Maybe it will help someone. I have 8 Modals on page and I have 8 conditionals.I guess you can use conditional in channel. :)

```
{if last_segment == 'Modal8'}  //Modal8 can be changed to any url: latestnews or smth.
$("#Modal8").foundation('reveal', 'open'); 
</script>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.hash){
    $(document).ready(function () {
      let $blockHash = $(window.location.hash);
      //console.log($blockHash);
      if (($blockHash.length > 0) && ($blockHash.hasClass('reveal'))){
        $blockHash.foundation('open');//foundation 6
      }
    });
}
```